# Remove launcher icon for uninstalled snap app?

Tags: gnome-shell, snap, .desktop

I installed Cantor from the software center.
(I didn't realize it would install the snap version, which I did not want). I then removed it using `snap remove cantor` from the command line.

However the Cantor launcher icon still appears in the Gnome-shell "app grid".

I checked `~/.local/share/applications/` and `/usr/share/applications/` and there is no `*.desktop` file for Cantor present in either location.

How can I remove this launcher icon?

Comment: Per the linked question, the offending `*.desktop` file is in `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/`